# Value of isBannerLoaded Property of a ADBannerView

Tags: iphone, ios, iad, adbannerview

who is the responsible for setting the value of isBannerLoaded Property of a ADBannerView

Answer (score 1):

It is set by the `ADBannerView` itself when it has downloaded a banner. It's a read-only property, so you can't change it yourself anyway.

From the iOS SDK documentation:

> A Boolean value that states whether the banner view has downloaded an
> advertisement. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isBannerLoaded) BOOL bannerLoaded
>
> Banner views automatically download new advertisements in the background. This property returns YES if an advertisement is loaded; NO otherwise.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/Reference/ADBannerView_Ref/Reference/Reference.html